# How to use the TBB in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, tbb

I am trying to use the TBB in the Qt Creator. I am using the Qt 4.7 and TBB 3.0, below is my setting in .pro.

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\tbb30\include
LIBS += C:\tbb30\lib\ia32\vc10\*.lib
```

My sample code is very simple:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    tbb::concurrent_vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(4);

    std::cout<<v.size();

    return a.exec();
}
```

But the program exit with the code -1073741515

Anyone use the TBB in the Qt Creator before?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

in LIBS, I don't think you can use joker characters (*, ?). You need to use the actual name of the lib. Note that you can specify a search path  for libs, then the lib name in "short format". If you aim at cross-compilation, it can be useful.

Here is an example to link Open Ssl (might be useful for you)

```
LIBS += -L$${OPEN_SSL}/lib
LIBS += -llibeay32
LIBS += -lssleay32
```

Concerning your error code, what compiler are you using (mingwin or visual?). In any case, you can check the generated command to try to understand why it goes wrong (the linker command). Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I can use the *, because it's ok when I use it for OpenCV. By the way, when I use the actual name of the lib, it still gave me the same error

Comment: then the error is in your linker : are you sure you're linking same architecture (no visual 2008 vs 2005, itanium vs x86,32 vs 64 bits). Common problem is linking mingwin sdk vs visual libraries, which have different ABIs => check where your error comes from (exact linker message / command) and update your post

Comment: I don't quite understand what your meaning. I download the binary for win from the official site. And finish all work simply in Qt Creator. When I check the folder under the lib folder. There are only version for vs8 vs9 and vs10, no mingwin version.

Comment: I was talking about your Qt sdk, not mingwin : as you said, you only have versions of TBB for Visual Studio, so if your Qt is compiled with mingwin or your Qt creator is configured to use mingwin, you'll have issues.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I forget to copy the dll files to the correct location. I can use the TBB now.